How to Access Fields in application/vnd.oracle.adf.resourceitem+json Response in WSO2 Integration Studio?
I'm currently working on a project in WSO2 Integration Studio, where I need to retrieve and process data from an external API. The challenge I'm facing is that the API response is in the application/vnd.oracle.adf.resourceitem+json content type.
In the past, I have worked with APIs that returned responses in application/json, and I could easily access specific fields using expressions like json-eval($.Products).
However, I'm unsure how to properly access and manipulate the fields in the application/vnd.oracle.adf.resourceitem+json response format. How can I extract and process the fields from this content type to save them as properties for further processing in my sequence?
Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated.

First, we have to assign a message builder for this message format. Please refer [1] for more details. As per my brief research application/vnd.oracle.adf.resourceitem+json can be treated as a JSON. So, we can register the same message builder we use for application/json
(org.wso2.micro.integrator.core.json.JsonStreamFormatter)
After that we should be able to access message fields using json-path expressions.
[1] https://mi.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/message-builders-formatters/message-builders-and-formatters/

Thank you Lahiru for the answer, I'm struggling a little to understand what should be changed in the message formatters/builders, can you please elaborate further ?

Solved the issue by adding this property after calling my api and the content type changed to application/json:
